DataGrid C# enable scrolling but disabled all other events like select rows etc
I am using DataGrid class (I cannot switch to DataGridView so please do not offer solutions that work for DataGridView atm).
The pickle is that the users want to be able to scroll but there seems to be no way to do that aside from setting Enabled property to true which allows the users to enter things in the grid by typing and selecting rows - all this should not be allowed.
Is there any way to allow users to scroll but not allow them to do anything else?

According to the docs there is a ReadOnly Property.

@Ralf - yes I am using it but it still allows the user to select row. Seems to be no onRowSelected event or something like that...

Weird requirement. If you want it like being completely disabled but still has scrolling you may try setting enabled to false again. Size the Datagrid to show all rows without scrolling or/and if scrollbars can be disabled on a DataGrid disable it. And then throw the Datagrid on a panel sized the way you need it and use the scrollbar of the panel instead.
